# How to have input field already have the 'clicked on' look without having to click it?

Tags: html, css, input

I want the input field to already have the clicked on look so when you look at the input field the '|' is already flashing without having someone having clicked on it?

It gives the search field a more welcoming touch

Here is my HTML for that field:

```
<input type="text" name="search" size="36" value="" 
style="background-color:white;border: 
solid 1px #ffffff; height: 30px; font-size:19px; font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light;
font-weight: 1;
vertical-align:9px;color:#bbb" 
onfocus="if(this.value == ''){this.value = 
'';this.style.color='#363D42'}" />
```

Thanks!

James

Comment: Just my opinion, but as a user, this would confuse me. There is a reason a focused field LOOKS focused.

Comment: Aside from the coding, where would I be able to find what I need? Is there a term for what I'm looking for?

Comment: James, Do you want it to simply "look" focused, or do you want it to actually BE focused? If the latter, the term you want is "autofocus".  If so, you may want to edit the question to clarify. This would benefit people looking for the same solution.

If the prior, I agree with @Nikki9696.  We would be interested in knowing why you want it to appear but not actually be focused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your intent is to have it *actually focused* as well, you could do that in javascript:

Add an ID to your input node: id="myID"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myID").focus();
</script>
```

Also, HTML 5 has an autofocus attribute:

```
<input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You `focus()` it:

```
document.getElementById('foo').focus();
```

To make it un-focused, you `blur()` it:

```
document.getElementById('foo').blur();
```